# How can I move an icon to a different place on the dock?

Tags: macos, dock, icon

Using El Capitan (10.11.6) on a MacBook Pro. I want to move an app icon to a different location on the Dock. I can get it on the dock but can't figure out how to move it from the default location.

Comment: [moving app icons in the dock](https://gfycat.com/ClearcutUnluckyAndeancondor#?speed=0.5)

Comment: That simple click and drag doesn't work for me. I thought it should be that simple. The fact that it doesn't work for me is probably related to another issue: I can't click and drag an icon to move the file from one folder to another in the Finder. I have to command-click and drag. That works to move a file from one folder to another but it doesn't work to move the icons on the dock. I have tried to find some Setting to change this so I don't need to press the command key, but I can't find anything. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Click and drag: put the cursor on the icon you want to move, then click and hold while dragging the icon right or left to the position you want.

Comment: I have tried that and it doesn't work for me. I thought it should be that simple. The fact that it doesn't work for me is probably related to another issue: I can't click and drag an icon to move the file from one folder to another in the Finder. I have to command-click and drag. That works to move a file from one folder to another but it doesn't work to move the icons on the dock. I have tried to find some Setting to change this so I don't need to press the command key, but I can't find anything. Any suggestions?